# Individually upgrading packages

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, apt

Is it possible to upgrade just a single package and its dependencies to their latest version?

I know its recommended to do a total upgrade, but when you are in a hurry or are in short of bandwidth, you can't take total upgrade as an option:

### Example Scenario

> I 've just added a new ppa of vlc...
>
> Runs `sudo apt-get upgrade`; slow connection
>
> Shows a huge estimate of time an bandwidth
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'s it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

This will also upgrade a single, already installed package.